# Python Count The Different Values From Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If i have a dataframe:

```
A                         B         C
0.0285714285714285        4         0.11428571
0.107142857142857         4         0.42857143
0.007142857142857         6         0.04285714
1.2                       4         5.5
1.5                       3         3
```

Desired output is;

```
A*B                    C                       Difference            
0.114285714285714‬      0.11428571          0.000000004285714‬            
0.428571428571428‬      0.42857143         -0.000000001428572‬
0.042857142857142‬      0.04285714          0.000000002857142‬
4.8                    5.5                        -0.7
4.5                    3                           1.5

Count: 2
```

I want to ignore the like 3 rows, because the difference is very small. only the first digit after the comma should be included.

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Because values in column `A` are objects (obviously strings):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)
```

If not working, because bad values (e.g. some strings) - bad values are repalced by `NaN`s:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
```

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for set new column by condition with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
#multiple columns
df['A*B'] = df["A"]*df["B"]
#subtract to Series
diff = df['A*B'] - df['C']
#create mask
mask = diff.between(-0.1, 0.1)

df["difference"] = diff.mask(mask, 0)
print (df)
          A  B         C       A*B  difference
0  0.028571  4  0.114286  0.114286         0.0
1  0.107143  4  0.428571  0.428571         0.0
2  0.007143  6  0.042857  0.042857         0.0
3  1.200000  4  5.500000  4.800000        -0.7
4  1.500000  3  3.000000  4.500000         1.5

print (f'Count: {(~mask).sum()}')
Count: 2
```

If order is important add [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
df.insert(0, 'A*B',  df.pop("A")*df.pop("B"))
diff = df['A*B'] - df['C']
mask = diff.between(-0.1, 0.1)

df["difference"] = diff.mask(mask, 0)
print (df)
        A*B         C  difference
0  0.114286  0.114286         0.0
1  0.428571  0.428571         0.0
2  0.042857  0.042857         0.0
3  4.800000  5.500000        -0.7
4  4.500000  3.000000         1.5


print (f'Count: {(~mask).sum()}')
Count: 2
```

Comment: I got this; TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Comment: @Salih - What is `print (df['C'].dtype)` ?

Comment: the type is "float64"

Comment: @Salih - And `print (df['A'].dtype)` with `print (df['B'].dtype)` ?

Comment: for A object, for B int64.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` to check whether the result is significant enough:

```
df["difference"] = np.where((df["A"]*df["B"]-df["C"]>=0.1)|(df["A"]*df["B"]-df["C"]<=-0.1),df["A"]*df["B"]-df["C"],0)

print (df)

#
          A  B         C  difference
0  0.028571  4  0.114286         0.0
1  0.107143  4  0.428571         0.0
2  0.007143  6  0.042857         0.0
3  1.200000  4  5.500000        -0.7
4  1.500000  3  3.000000         1.5
```